# Converting to different timezone using UTC Offset in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to convert to specific time zone from UTC time using UTC time Offset.

I tried as following:

```
 DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
 TimeSpan offSet = TimeSpan.Parse(timeoffset.ToString());
 DateTime newDateTime = utcDateTime.Add(offSet);
```

But it doesn't adds up the offset with UTC. 
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

```
 DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
 TimeSpan offSet = TimeSpan.Parse(timeoffset.ToString());
 DateTime newDateTime = utcDateTime.Add(offSet);
```

instead of using `TimeSpan.Parse(timeoffset.ToString());` i used `TimeSpan.FromHours((double)offset);`

```
  DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
     TimeSpan offSet = TimeSpan.FromHours((double)offset);
     DateTime newDateTime = utcDateTime.Add(offSet);
```

It worked perfectly fine for me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a simple way, here change time zone as per your requirement.

```
public static DateTime GetISTDate()
{
     DateTime utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
     var ISTtime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
     return ISTtime;
}
```

Comment: i Cant use TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById since i dont know the timezone id. AM storing UTCOffset time in DB and reading from there.

Comment: @ShivaPrasad: It seems like you are trying to get datetime on basic of off set.

Comment: @ShivaPrasad: Then you need to do in this way:  `utcDateTime + offSet;`